# Как проверить объект на дубликат перед сохранением или сравнить хэш сериализованных объектов java spring data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, repository

Есть класс Test с transient полями. Мне нужно убедиться перед сохранением в бд, что существующий объект изменен и сохранить его как новый, в противном случае не сохранять. Equals реализован по всем полям, его менять нельзя. Нужно сравнить по отдельным полям, избегая transient. Предлагали решение проверять хэш сериализованного объекта, не совсем понял суть. Возможно есть best practices?

Comment: Проблема в сравнении? Сделайте компаратором

Comment: Вроде разобрался с сериализацией, благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Придумал такое решение. Битье по рукам приветствуется!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: Такое решение было принято реализовать для избежания transient полей.